# How to safely let users run arbitrary Ruby code?

Tags: ruby

I realize this sounds a little crazy, but I'm working on a project for which I need a server to run user-provided Ruby code and return the result.

I'm looking to prevent something like this:

```
system("rm -rf /")
eval("something_evil")
# etc...
```

I'm sure there must be some reasonably safe way to do this, as it already exists at places like tryruby.org. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Three suggestions:

1) Take a look at Ruby [taint levels](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/taint.html). This provides some degree of protection against, `eval('evil_code')` type things, etc.

2) Unless user's actually need access to the local file system, use something like [fakefs](http://ozmm.org/posts/fakefs.html)

3) No matter what else you do [follow Tronic's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573012/how-to-safely-let-users-run-arbitrary-ruby-code/2573033#2573033) (can be a pain to setup, but limited chroot jails are about the only way to make absolutely sure that user's cannot access resources you don't explicitly want them to).

Answer (score 3):

Run the program ptraced with a whitelist of allowed syscalls, as user/group nobody, with resource limits (memory usage etc), in a minimal chroot.

Answer (score 2):

A "blank slate" is an object stripped of (most of) its methods.
A "clean room" is an object within which you evaluate potentially unsafe room.
If you evaluate the code in a "clean room" which is also a "blank slate," cranking the safe level up as high as it will go, you will afford yourself a great deal of protection.  Nothing in security is sure, so this should be considered a layer in your security, not necessarily the *only* layer.

[This answer shows how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045324/executing-user-supplied-ruby-code-on-a-web-server/2046076#2046076).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but then came across [eval.so](http://eval.so/) and decided to write an API wrapper for it, called [Sandie](https://github.com/codets/sandie). It's as easy as:

```
sandie = Sandie.new(language: 'ruby')
# => #<Sandie:0x00000002e30650>
sandie.evaluate(code: 'puts "hello world"')
# => {"stdout"=>"hello world\n", "stderr"=>"", "wallTime"=>487, "exitCode"=>0}
```

It also supports a whole lot of other languages as well like C#, Perl, Lua, and Java.