# A string (thats looks like an array) into an array Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have an output from an API that look like this... (its a string)

```
[[2121212,212121,asd],[2323232,23232323,qasdasd]]
```

Its a string - not an array. I want to convert it to an array and then extract the first two elements in each array in the nested array to:

```
[2121212,212121],[2323232,23232323]
```

What's the best way to do this ruby? I could use regexp and extract - but basically the string is already an array, however the class is a string.

I tried

```
array.push(response)
```

but that just put the string in to the array as one element. I guess what would be nice is a to_array method

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby: Parsing a string representation of nested arrays into an Array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477127/ruby-parsing-a-string-representation-of-nested-arrays-into-an-array)

Comment: This is not the same - neither JSON nor eval will handle strings without quotation marks. If the strings are so simple as `asd`, I'd just added quotations marks to them by regexp and then used JSON.parse or eval: `eval str.gsub(/([a-zA-Z]+)/, '"\1"')`

Comment: Lukas - sorry the strings will change - they will always be syntactically the same ie [element, element,element] I could call a .to_json method on it and have it return as "[element, element, element']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is a JSON response (and if so, it is badly malformed and you should talk to the people that are responsible for this) you could write something like:

```
require 'json'

input= '[[2121212,212121,Asd],[2323232,23232323,qasdasd]]'
input.gsub!(/([A-Za-z ]+)/,'"\1"')
json = JSON.parse input
output = json.map{|x| x[0...2]}
p output
```

this prints

```
[[2121212, 212121], [2323232, 23232323]]
```

Comment: if your code also parses valid json, you should improve the regex in such a manner that it will not quote already quoted strings, though. but i'll leave that up to you :)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use regular expression anyway if not eval (shrudder...), this is the shortest one

```
str = "[[2121212,212121,asd],[2323232,23232323,qasdasd],[2424242,24242424,qasdasd]]"
p str.scan(/(\d+),(\d+)/)

=>[["2121212", "212121"], ["2323232", "23232323"], ["2424242", "24242424"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using eval is very bad but I have no other easy option.

```
test_str = "[[2121212,212121,asd],[2323232,23232323,qasdasd]]"
test_str.gsub!(/([a-z]+)/) do
  "'#{$1}'" 
 end
 => "[[2121212,212121,'asd'],[2323232,23232323,'qasdasd']]"
test_array = eval(test_str)
 => [[2121212, 212121, "asd"], [2323232, 23232323, "qasdasd"]]
test_array.each do |element|
  element.delete(element.last)
end
 => [[2121212, 212121], [2323232, 23232323]]
```

Comment: You definitely has other options than `eval`. Namely `JSON.parse`. Also, your gsub can be written without the block: `str.gsub!(/([a-z]+)/', '"\\1"')`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but JSON.parse("[[2121212,212121,asd],[2323232,23232323,qasdasd]]")
JSON::ParserError: 399: unexpected token at 'asd],[2323232,23232323,qasdasd]]'

Comment: @soundar: but the thing you are `eval`ling could be just as easily `JSON.parse`d if you only changed the line `"'#{$1}'"` to `"\"#$1\""`. You would then produce something like `'[[21212,212,"asd"],…]'`, which is valid JSON.