# How do I convert a string to an array of arrays?

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

I have a string with an array of arrays inside:

```
"[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]"
```

Can I convert this to the array of arrays, without using `eval` or a regular expression, `gsub`, etc.?

Can I make turn it into:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

Comment: without using eval or reg ex, gsub, etc. so what you want to do it with?

Comment: is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: i think `eval` is the most simple way, if you worry about security, check the string with regex to make sure. but seems you don't want both.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid `eval`? How much simpler can it be than `eval("[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]")`?

Comment: I have been told that 'eval' is a bad idea unless you really have to.

Comment: Also, I don't really know how to use reg ex yet (still learning), but am fine using it if I understand it

Comment: @stinkydiesel, I suggest using a different format if construction of that string is under your control.  Like for example json so that its more readable and using JSON.parse() instead of using regex.  But regex is undoubtedly powerful and if you say you are still learning then yes, absolutely continue with the learning.

Comment: @vinodadhikary How is the string not already json?

Comment: @jcsanyi, I guess that's why I used it in my proposed answer below :).  I added a new vocabulary for the OP'er as he constrained his options to `eval`, `regex` and `gsub`.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477127/ruby-parsing-a-string-representation-of-nested-arrays-into-an-array

Comment: @stinkydiesel, `eval` is the right tool for the job in this case. Only if the string is user input than it *could* be a bad idea.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

How about the following?

```
require 'json'
arr = JSON.parse("[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]") # => [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
arr[0] # => [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 9):

The same can be done using Ruby standard libaray documentation - [`YAML`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/index.html):

```
require 'yaml'

YAML.load("[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]")
 # => [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```